# Read data from textfile and validate it using Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have encounter a problem while validating the data from a textfile. I can only validate my ID number only the other fields is not working.

Below is my Java code:

```
public void readBorrowerData() {
String fnm="", snm="", pcd="";
int num=0, id=1;
try { 
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new File("borrowers.txt"));
  scnr.useDelimiter("\\s*#\\s*");
  if(id < 0 || snm == null || fnm == null || num < 0){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Try again", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  } else {
      while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
          id  = scnr.nextInt();
          snm = scnr.next();
          fnm = scnr.next();
          num = scnr.nextInt();
          pcd = scnr.next();
          borrowers.put(new Integer(id), new Borrower(id, snm, fnm, num, pcd));
      }
  }
  scnr.close();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  System.out.printf("%d %s %s %d %s\n", id, snm, fnm, num, pcd);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage(),
      "fetch of next token failed ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Plz show us the content of your text file also

Comment: @johny this is the content which it shows :

001#  Jones#          Jack#           41#   NX4 4XZ#

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `scnr.nextInt()` with `scnr.next()`. Use `I'd = Integer.parseInt(scnr.next());` instead. Sorry if this was not the case

Comment: I mean Use `id = Integer.parseInt(scnr.next());` Auto correction on mobiles can be really annoying sometimes:)

Comment: It seems it does not validate the other fields such as the firstname and surname..

Comment: Change `while (scnr.hasNextInt())` to `while (scnr.hasNext())` as well

Comment: i tried it but the programm is not reading the borrower data now. i guess i cannot change the scnr.hasNext() in the while loop